# For Each Variant in Object Array

Tags: excel, vba, variables, object, for-loop

I think I am missing something fundamental error here, but I can't figure it out.

I have about 64 cells in a spreadsheet that I want to set as variables to use in other equations throughout the spreadsheet.  It's important that they are variables for ease of calculations, and because their location changes dynamically depending on other user input.  I initially had the following code which worked perfectly fine:

```
Set Ap1thV = range("B32")
Set Ap1tuV = range("B33")
Set Ap1thVdef = range("C32")
Set Ap1tuVdef = range("C33")
```

and so on and so on for 64 cells (8 columns by 8 rows).  The variables are set publicly as objects.  Is there a faster way to set all of these variables?  It slows down my macro significantly each time it runs, but it needs to run often during the course of the program.

I have tried to consolidate by using the following:

```
cellnums = 32
For Each Vcelldefs In Array(Ap1thV, Ap1tuV, Ap2thV, Ap2tuV, Ap3thV, Ap3tuV, Ap4thV, Ap4tuV)
    Set Vcelldefs = Range("B" & cellnums)
    cellnums = cellnums + 1
Next Vcelldefs
cellnums = 32
For Each Vdefcelldefs In Array(Ap1thVdef, Ap1tuVdef, Ap2thVdef, Ap2tuVdef, Ap3thVdef, Ap3tuVdef, Ap4thVdef, Ap4tuVdef)
    Set Vdefcelldefs = Range("C" & cellnums)
    cellnums = cellnums + 1
Next Vdefcelldefs
cellnums = 32
```

This code runs, but the variables are set to Nothing, which throws back errors any time these cells/variables are referenced or used in calculations.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated!  If I can explain it better, just ask.  Thanks,

Comment: you need to use array instead this variables `Ap1thV, Ap1tuV, Ap2thV, Ap2tuV, Ap3thV, Ap3tuV, Ap4thV, Ap4tuV` like this: `Dim Ap1thV(1 to 32) as Range`

Comment: Ap1thV is cell B32, Ap1tuV is cell B33, Ap2thV is cell B34, Ap2tuV is cell B35 and so on.  BUT it only goes through Ap4tuV which is cell B39.  There are 8 columns with 8 rows.  And each cell needs to have its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

Each time those for loops iterate, it's overwriting the current object.  You would need something like separate arrays to hold those range objects.  You'd have to start indexing the arrays at 0, if the following makes sense:

```
Dim arrVcelldefs(32)
Dim arrVdefcelldefs(32)

cellnums = 32
For Each Vcelldefs In Array(Ap1thV, Ap1tuV, Ap2thV, Ap2tuV, Ap3thV, Ap3tuV, Ap4thV, Ap4tuV)
    arrVcelldefs(cellnums-32) = Range("B" & cellnums)
    cellnums = cellnums + 1
Next Vcelldefs
cellnums = 32
For Each Vdefcelldefs In Array(Ap1thVdef, Ap1tuVdef, Ap2thVdef, Ap2tuVdef, Ap3thVdef, Ap3tuVdef, Ap4thVdef, Ap4tuVdef)
    arrVdefcelldefs(cellnums-32) = Range("C" & cellnums)
    cellnums = cellnums + 1
Next Vdefcelldefs
cellnums = 32
```

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what this is doing.  But I'm still getting the error in other parts of the sheet that an object is required.  I need to be able to reference Ap1thV and others throughout the code... I'm not sure this accomplishes that task.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **Dim** ing them as **Static** and then Setting them only once.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're storing those Range objects, but all you really want is the value in the cell. You're probably doing

```
Set Ap1thVdef = Range("B23")
```

then later using it as

```
MyResult = 100 * Ap1thVdef.Value
```

It would be better if instead of storing the Range object to just store the value. Also, since it appears from your example that the at least some of the cells are contiguous, you can assign the Value of a multi-cell range to an array and get a 2-dim array with all of the values.

Assume you have 16 values you need to use from a spreadsheet. You don't need to populate those values every time it runs, but you do need to change them on occasion. Set up an IntitializeVars procedure that will populate two 8 row arrays based on the ranges you provide to the procedure.

Also, include an optional Boolean argument to force the arrays to repopulate even if they already have something in them.

```
Public vaAp As Variant
Public vaApDef As Variant

Public Sub InitializeVars(rAp As Range, rApDef As Range, Optional ByVal Force As Boolean = False)

    If Not IsArray(vaAp) Or Force Then
        'This creates a two dimensional array
        vaAp = rAp.Value
    End If

    If Not IsArray(vaApDef) Or Force Then
        'This creates a two dimensional array
        vaApDef = rApDef.Value
    End If

    'Now you have two, 2-dim arrays that are full of the values
    'from the ranges you passed in

End Sub

Sub test()

    'Put your values into the public arrays
    InitializeVars Sheet1.Range("B32").Resize(8, 1), Sheet1.Range("C32").Resize(8, 1)

    'Use the values from the arrays in your business logic
    Debug.Print 100 * vaAp(2, 1)
    Debug.Print 3 + vaApDef(6, 1)

    'Now the something changed and I need to fix the arrays
    'to point to new locations. I set the last argument to TRUE
    'so the arrays repopulate even if there's already something
    'in them
    InitializeVars Sheet1.Range("D32").Resize(8, 1), Sheet1.Range("E32").Resize(8, 1), True

    'use the new arrays
    Debug.Print 100 * vaAp(2, 1)
    Debug.Print 3 + vaApDef(6, 1)

End Sub
```